# Как задать функцию в коде на C++, так чтобы ее можно было вызвать из кода на C?

Tags: c, c++

Как задать функцию в коде на C++, так чтобы ее можно было вызвать из кода на C?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если нужно использовать один и тот же заголовочный файл для C и C++ кода, можно обернуть определения функций таким образом.

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void doFirst();
void doSecond();

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Это работает, потому что макрос `__cplusplus` определен только в C++, но не в C.

Answer (score 4):

Нужно предварить объявление функции в коде на C++ модификатором extern "C". Например, так.

```
/* Объявление */
extern "C" void execute();

/* Определение */
void execute() {
}
```